# same length columns (with variable rows)?

Tags: css

I've searched around but can't find what I'm looking for. I'm attempting to do something rather specific, but I may just need direction in applying a more general solution.

I would like to create two columns, the left one being split into two rows, for a total of 3 internal divs. (Perhaps they shouldn't be divs; you'll let me know.) The width of both columns is predetermined, but the height of the 3 divs isn't. A little picture:

`|---|`
`|A| |`
`|-|C|`
`|B| |`
`|---|`

I would like the following conditions to be met:

- height(A)+height(B)==height(C);
- height(A)==height(B)

I created a jsfiddle, with A green, B yellow and C red; the background of the whole thing is blue.  If the jsfiddle were to fulfil my requirements, the blue would always be hidden:
http://jsfiddle.net/266p3/1/

Can someone give me a hand or point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: Could a table with `rowspan` work? Assuming the data is tabular data to begin with I guess

Comment: Instead of using divs to imitate a table, use a table and use `rowspan` as @JasonSperske suggested. Check out [w3School's explanation of tables](www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp).

Comment: I'm not sure that a `rowspan` would work.  Please see my clarification of the problem in my comment to Trevan Hetzel's answer, below.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to use a table for this. By positioning the parent `#wrapper` to `relative` and setting a height (could be 100% if your `html` and `body` is set to 100%, or a pixel value as I have in the fiddle), you can then position the columns and rows `relative` to the parent container. This allows you to set the rows' heights to 50%.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/266p3/7/

**The updated CSS:**

```
#wrapper{
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
}

#col1{
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}

#row1{
    background-color: green;
    height: 50%;
}

#row2{
    position: relative;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 50%;
}

#col2{
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

There is probably a better way to organize the CSS and even the markup for that matter, but I just added on/modified your existing fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  However, I think I wasn't clear enough in my question.

The issue is that I don't know the heights of A, B and C yet.  What I'm therefore looking to achieve is:
- As A (or B) grow, B (or A) needs to match it; also, C then needs to be the sum of A and B;
- As C grows, both A and B need to match its height.

In my particular case, A has text, which is vertically aligned to the bottom.  Both B and C have images.  The whole page is responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `<table>` would be very usefull in this situation..

Following html can solve the problem

```
<table>
    <tr class='equalRow'>
         <td>row1 col1</td>
         <td rowspan='3'>common col</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='equalRow'>
         <td>row2 col1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Check the [Fiddle for demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mayekarsaurabh/266p3/4/)

Answer (score 0):

*[LIVE EXAMPLE](http://jsbin.com/ehiNabUF/2/edit)*

```
<table>
   <tr><td>A</td><td rowspan="2">C</td></tr>
   <tr><td>B</td></tr>
</table>
```

```
table{
  height:300px;
}
table td{
  background:#eee;
  padding:10px;
}
table td:first-child{
  height:50%;
  background:#eee;
  padding:10px;
}
```